# How to find out the size of an String[] in Jasper

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I have an Jasper report that put my data into csv and I need something like this:

```
$F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ").size()>=2 ? ($F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")[0]+" "+$F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")[1]+" "+$F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")[2]) : $F{OBSERVATII}
```

but Jasper throws me an

> Cannot invoke size() on the array type String[]

If I put only

```
$F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")[0]+" "+$F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")[1]+" "+$F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")[2])
```

then, when I have an simple word string (without spaces) it gives me an error...

Comment: [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). [Java String array: is there a size of method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/921384/876298)

Comment: It's not about Java String array... the errors I get are from Jasper. In java I only need the .jasper file (from the .jrxml) and I'm not reaching the .jasper with those build errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Edit:

The correct syntax for Jasper Reports is this.  Evidently Jasper does not like using the property .length in this context.

```
 Arrays.asList($F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")).size() ? blah...
```

Don't you want the length property for an array of strings, rather than the size method which does not work with an array?

```
.length >= 2 ? blah
```

Edited to say:

You said Jasper does not like the above syntax, but it's what you should use.  You could try:

```
(String[] $F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")).length>=2 ? blah...
```

Or

```
Arrays.asList($F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")).size() ? blah...
```

That will convert your array to a list and use the size method.  I don't know if Jasper will like that or not, if not, I suppose their expression editor sucks.

Comment: I've tried .length but Jasper Expresion Editor gives me "The current expression is not valid. Please verify it!". I have to put $F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ").length()>=2 but that gives me "Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]"...

Comment: @MihaiG That's because `length` is a property and not a method. Lose the parentheses and it should work (i.e. mikeb's code is exactly correct).

Comment: Arrays.asList($F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")).size()>=2 works,
(String[] $F{OBSERVATII}.split(" ")).length>=2 - don't, but it's ok, thanks!