# Trying to get the size of an inner arraylists of class object inside an outer arraylist of arraylists

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

i have an array list of arraylists of object type trying to get the size of a specific array list but i keep getting the size of the the whole arraylist

```
healthyKoalas = new ArrayList<Koala>();
hKoalas = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Koala>>();

public void hkoala(int x)
    {
         for (int i=0; i<x; i++) // x is the number of healthy koalas in an observation point
         {
             int age = (int)(Math.random()*18)+1; 
             Koala k = new Koala(age); 
             addHKoala(k);
             healthyKoalas.sort(Comparator.comparing(Koala::getAge).reversed());
             //Collections.sort(healthyKoalas, Collections.reverseOrder());
            }
        hKoalas.add(healthyKoalas);
    }
```

then when i try

```
hKoalas.get(x).size();
```

it gives me the number of all the koala objects while i want to get the size of a specific inner arraylist

Comment: public void hkoala(int x)
    {
         for (int i=0; i<x; i++) // x is the number of healthy koalas in an observation point
         {
             int age = (int)(Math.random()*18)+1; 
             Koala k = new Koala(age); 
             addHKoala(k);
             healthyKoalas.sort(Comparator.comparing(Koala::getAge).reversed());
            }
        hKoalas.add(healthyKoalas);
    }    // when i try to use hkoalas.get(x).size it gives me the total number of koala objects in the outer arraylist while im trying to get the size of an inner arraylist

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684644/11754886) answer your question?

Comment: Please provide more info, for example the arraylist(s), so we can understand your point better.

Comment: ArrayList<healthyKoalas> = new ArrayList<Koala>();
hKoalas<ArrayList<healthyKoalas>> = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Koala>>();

Comment: public void hkoala(int x)
    {
         for (int i=0; i<x; i++) 
         {
             int age = (int)(Math.random()*18)+1; 
             Koala k = new Koala(age); 
             addHKoala(k);
             healthyKoalas.sort(Comparator.comparing(Koala::getAge).reversed());
             }
        hKoalas.add(healthyKoalas);
       }        the function to populate the arraylists

Comment: then when try to use hKoalas.get(x).size() i get the number of every k object in the arraylist not the numer at position x

Answer (score 1):

Given `hKoalas = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Koala>>();`, then `hKoalas.get(1).size()` **will** give you the number of elements of the second 'inner list' (index 1 = the second one in the store, as index 0 is the first one). If you think it is returning the count of ALL koalas across all the inner lists, you've got another bug in your code and you have misidentified what's happening.